# Manipulating values in C

Tags: c

Ok so during my break between semesters I am learning C. I am using my old projects from an assembly class that I had written and converting them into C. The program that I am working on takes in an integer and then prints out the int, hex, binary values for 2's comp, 1's comp, neg 1's comp, neg signed mag. I have written this so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int counter = 0, bit = 0;
    long int number, binVal, hexVal = 0, i = 1, remainder;

    printf("Enter an integer number: ");
    scanf("%ld", &number);

    printf("2's compliment:\t%ld\t", number);
    binVal == &number;
    while(binVal != 0)
    {
        remainder = binVal % 10;
        hexVal = hexVal + remainder * i;
        i = i * 2;
        binVal = binVal / 10;
    }

    printf("%lX\t", hexVal);

    for (counter = 31; counter >= 0; counter--)
    {
        bit = number >> counter;
        printf("%s",(bit & 1) ? "1" : "0");
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

My question is this. As I have coded it, if I enter the value 15, I get the correct 32 bit binary value but my hex value = 7. If I enter 1111 I get the correct hex value of F but I get the binary value of 00000000000000000000010001010111. Now I know that the int value gets stored as 2's comp in memory but im not sure why Im getting the wrong values.  Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is this line of code correct ? `binVal == &number;`

Comment: no that was me trying things out.  it should be binVal = number;

Comment: Doubt that `binVal == &number;` is what you want. Probably you want `binVal = number;`

Comment: Thanks Richard I had corrected that.

Comment: So you enter number in binary or in base 10 ?

Comment: I want to enter the number as an base 10 integer. but when I do I get the wrong hex value but the correct binary value.  if i enter it as a binary number i get the correct hex value but the wrong binary value

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that's actually having the problem.

Comment: To get hex digits you should be using `16` in your modulus and division, not 10.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do in that loop that sets `hexVal`. Why are you multiplying `i` by 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wher using printf `printf("%lX\t", hexVal);` you just have to pass
base 10 value, no need for previous transaction.

These lines of code convert binary to base 10:

```
while(binVal != 0)
{
    remainder = binVal % 10;
    hexVal = hexVal + remainder * i;
    i = i * 2;
    binVal = binVal / 10;
}
```

Which is what you don't want.
If you want to print hex value, you can just call

```
printf("%lX\t", number);
```

Or do it manually

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int counter = 0;
    long int number, remainder;

    printf("Enter an integer number: ");
    scanf("%ld", &number);
    printf("\n");

    printf("2's compliment:\t%ld\t\n", number);

    printf("0x");
    for (counter = 28; counter >= 0; counter-= 4)
    {
        remainder = (number >> counter) & 0xF;
        if (remainder < 10)
            printf("%d", remainder);
        else
            printf("%c", 'A' + remainder - 10);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (counter = 31; counter >= 0; counter--)
    {
        printf("%d", (number >> counter) & 1);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the printf statement works.  But the manual way seems to be having the same issue i had before.  using the manual way if you enter 15 the result is 0x77777777 it should be 0x0F.  I will dig further into this thank you for your help

Comment: I did check this code with 15 at ideone.com and output was correct:
Enter an integer number: 
2's compliment: 15 
0x0000000F
00000000000000000000000000001111

Comment: yeah im an idiot, had the wrong logic in the if statement.  I fixed it!! thank you again Nick!!

Comment: @LD50 No problem ^_^